# Drools to rule excel sheet

Tags: drools, rule-engine

Just thinking is there a way to convert drl file to excel sheet using Drools APIs?

We are currently on Drools 5.3 But can use any version really.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello any takers please?

Comment: I dont think there is a way to do that. Maybe you can write up an api for it.

You can however convert an Excel sheet containing rules to a DRL file.

Comment: i have same requirement .will you please paste answer if you know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not API (at least supported by JBoss) to do what you are looking for.
You can try to parse the rules yourself and create a CSV or XLS file, but there is no out-of-the-box support for this.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.CR1/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e6019 - see 5.11.4 - Excel can read xml files...